# Is using the class-wrapper for thread-safe access to the object conform to C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Can I use this class-wrapper for thread-safe access to the object, and desired behavior conforms to C++11?

Main accent to the strings:

```
T* operator->() {
```

and

```
T& operator*() {
```

Note, I know that here optimal to use std::atomic<> for the integer(int), but in this code instead of int we can use any other object.

Version 2.0 by using [execute-around pointer idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer):

```
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

template<typename T>
class safe_obj {
    T obj;
    mutable std::mutex mtx;
    safe_obj(safe_obj<T> &) {}
    safe_obj<T>& operator=(safe_obj<T> &) {}

    class T_exclusive_lock {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> xlock;
    public:
         T*const self;
         T_exclusive_lock(T * const s, std::mutex& _mtx)
             :self(s), xlock(_mtx) {}

        T* operator -> () const {return self;}
        operator T&()  {return *self;}

        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &stream, T_exclusive_lock &obj) {
            stream << obj;
            return stream;
        }
    };

public:
    template<typename  Types>
    safe_obj(Types  args) : obj(args ) 
    { }

    T_exclusive_lock operator->() {
        return T_exclusive_lock(&obj, mtx);
    }    

    T_exclusive_lock* operator*() {
        return &T_exclusive_lock(&obj, mtx);
    }       
};

int main() {
    safe_obj<std::shared_ptr<int> > safe_int( std::make_shared<int>(10) );   

    auto lambda = [&safe_int]() {
        std::cout << safe_int->use_count() << std::endl;    // is that thread-safe? 
        std::cout << *safe_int << std::endl;    // is that thread-safe? 
        std::cout << *safe_int->get() << std::endl;    // is that thread-safe? 
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> thr_grp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) thr_grp.emplace_back(std::thread(lambda));
    for(auto &i : thr_grp) i.join();

    int b; std::cin >> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest std::shared_ptr and shared_ptr atomic access

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original code you provided didn't guarantee any thread-safety. Your `std::unique_lock`s unlock the mutex as soon as they get out of scope, which is prior to the use of the object you wanted to protect.

To achieve the desired result, you would need to declare another templated class (e.g. `locked_obj<T>`) which would represent the object in a locked state (by having a `unique_lock` on the `safe_obj`'s mutex) and return such an object from the overloaded operators. Such an object would be a temporary one and allow you to manipulate the guarded object during the lifetime of `locked_obj`. As temporary objects live until the end of current statement, use of such `safe_obj`s would be mostly transparent.

This technique is an application of [execute-around pointer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer) idiom.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited to the new version by using execute-around pointer idiom, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you applied the idiom correctly. However, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve in the `static_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>>(*safe_int)` line...

Comment: But why such templated pointer with execute-around pointer idiom is not present in the Boost-library, or is present?

Comment: I haven't noticed it in Boost. Why isn't it there? Maybe it isn't there *yet* (because nobody cared to put it tere) or maybe someone considered it and refused it due to the reasons Pete Becker stipulated in his answer. Use of such an idiom may lead to false sense of thread safety in some cases. Moreover, note that your implementation has a possible implicit caveat - dereferencing the same safe_obj more than once in the same statement would lead to a deadlock. It's quite easy to overcome (e.g. by returning a shared_ptr<T_exclusive_lock>), but this would turn impose a slight performance drop...

Comment: Avoid deadlock, it is easy by using std::recursive_mutex. The performance of this pointer will be enough for most non-critical to the speed of the cases.

Comment: You're right, `recursive_mutex`es are an easier way to go. I just thought they were deprecated, but the fact they were introduced to std:: in C++11 suggest that they are considered fine.

Comment: It's greate thing, it can't be deprecated. Such as std::shared_mutex, which will be added in C++14.

Answer (score 3):

Locking individual functions or locking accesses to an individual object does not guarantee thread safety; depending on the program, many operations require multiple function calls on the same object without interruption or operations on multiple objects without interruption. Thread safety has to be **designed** into an application; there are no library hacks that will make an application that isn't properly designed thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not thread-safe. By the time the accessor functions return, the mutex has been unlocked, so access to the object is not synchronised.

One approach is to overload assignment and conversion operators:

```
safe_obj & operator=(T const &t) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    obj = t;
    return *this;
}

operator T() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    return obj;
}
```

but this might get tedious if you want to provide all the compound assignment operators, and the conversion operator won't work if the object is not copyable.

Another approach would be to return an accessor object containing a `unique_lock`, which keeps the mutex locked as long as you have access to the object.